# Concatenar variables EditText java Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

estoy comenzando un pequeño proyecto del cual tengo unas lineas que me permiten crear un fichero ( son códigos de barras ), en ese fichero desearía que delante de cada lectura se añadiera un número que estaría en una variable que viene de un Edittext, el fichero se genera de un EditText multilínea ( como leo con una PDA cada lectura hace un salto de línea y es ahí donde quiero colocar esa variable.)
Con el código que tengo actualmente consigo poner esa variable delante de la lectura total:
ejemplo
109966332285  ( el número 10 es la variable)
9966332285   (esta sería la segunda línea.

Es lógico yo mismo sé, porque me pasa, concatenar la variable del EditText del número y con el de la lectura de los códigos.

Este es mi código:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et_nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_nombre);
    et_tienda = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_tienda);
    et_contenido = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_contenido);

//Metodo botón Guardar
public void Guardar(View view) {
    String nombre = et_nombre.getText().toString();
    String contenidos = et_contenido.getText().toString(); // original 29/01/2020
    String tienda = et_tienda.getText().toString();
    String contenido = tienda.concat(contenidos);    // solo añade al principio del fichero no en cada línea
    try {
        File tarjetaSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        Toast.makeText(this, tarjetaSD.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        File rutaArchivo = new File(tarjetaSD.getPath(), nombre);
        OutputStreamWriter crearArchivo =new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(rutaArchivo));
        //OutputStreamWriter crearArchivo = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(nombre, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE));
        crearArchivo.write(contenido);
        crearArchivo.flush();
        crearArchivo.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Guardado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        et_nombre.setText("");
        et_contenido.setText("");
        et_tienda.setText("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo guardar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Espero que alguien pueda orientarme para realizar la concatenación en el momento de cada lectura, gracias

---

pero no es eso , me he explicado mal , ahora mismo lo que obtengo es:

```
10996538124  // primera línea con tienda =10 y código 99xx
996582314    // segunda línea y sucesivas
998523475
```

y lo que quiero obtener es:

```
10996538124
10996582314
10998523475
```

que cada línea comience con el valor de tienda, perdón por explicarme mal, y gracias por la respuesta

---

te explico la estructura que busco en el fichero que guardo es esta:

esto es una línea de lectura:

```
1º valor  T  => es un valor fijo, siempre es T
2º valor  length de 6 vacío sangría derecha este tienda origen ejemplo "     6" 5 espacios vacios y número 6.
3º valor  length de 6 vacío sangría derecha este tienda destino ejemplo "    10" 4 espacios vacios y número 10 ( este Editext aún no lo he creado)
4º valor length de 25 vacio sangría izquierda ejemplo "9988665577221            " 13 dígitos del código de barras con sangría a la izquierda y los restantes vacios
5º valor length 10 aquí siempre será "0000000001"
```

Esa línea sería así:

```
T     6    109988665577221            0000000001
```

Esto sería una línea de lectura de código de barras, cada línea identifica T= traspaso, tienda de origen, tienda de destino, código de barras y unidad = 1

Gracias otra vez, estoy dándole más vueltas con String.fomat para cada variable pero me da error

Comment: No es muy entendible lo que quieres realizar, al parecer el problema no tiene que ver con lo que comentas en tu pregunta si no en el guardado. No se guarda el 10 o no se guardann las lineas, especifica u pregunta, considera revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Buenas, tienes razón lo expliqué fatal, si el problema es como lo quiero guardar, creo que ya lo expliqué mejor

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entendi, el problema es que solo estas concatenando la tienda una vez en un string pero queres que ese string aparezca en cada salto de linea.
No entiendo bien el por que o para que, pero te dejo una solucion que hara lo que necesitas.

```
//Agrego algunas lineas de tu codigo para poner en contexto la solucion.
String contenidos = et_contenido.getText().toString();
String tienda = et_tienda.getText().toString();
String contenido = tienda.concat(contenidos); 

contenido = contenido.replace("\n","\n"+tienda);// <-- Esta linea hara la magia

try {
  ...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, hace lo que necesitaba en la pregunta, pero me genera un problema, si elimino mi línea concat la primera línea no lleva la tienda por delante, hay forma de solventar esto, ( la estructura que busco es la siguiente

Comment: "T"+"     "+"tienda_origen + "    "+tienda+contenido+"0000000001"  el lenght de contenido debería ser de 25 comenzando por la izquierda, ya se que estoy abusando mucho

Comment: Todo esto es para intentar emular la generación de unso ficheros por parte de unos escaner antiguos , los cuales ya he reparado muchas veces y ya poco más dan de sí

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: nose que es T, tienda_origen y tienda. No le quites ninguna linea de lo que te muestro, sino no va a funcionar. Otra solucion para que trabajes mejor estos strings es hacer un split po \n y obtener cada codigo como un string separado, eso te ahorraria problemas, pero es mas engorroso